# Search in all directories

Tags: search, vim, grep, ack, findstr

I can't find out how to search in Vim in **all directories** with:

- grep
- ack
- findstring
- vimgrep

p.e. search "search-item" in all .txt files in c:\ and d:\ (including sub directories)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: *ack.vim* allow searching inside Vim. Example: `:Ack foo .`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following works for me

```
:vimgrep /<search>/ {c:,d:}/**/*.txt
```

Comment: You can write more then one pattern for `:vimgrep`. Also try `vimgrep /<search>/ {c:,d:}/**/*.txt` or even `vimgrep /<search>/ [cd]:/**/*.txt`.

Comment: @ZyX - Thank you, I had no idea. I've incorporated your comment into my answer.

Comment: I thought this was the solution but I noted that it freezes vim. I have to use ctrl-c to unfreeze my vim.

Comment: @Remonn - the command works allright but perhaps a bit slow on two drives? What happens if you try it on a smaller map?

Comment: @Lieven, partially found it. I can search a sub directory when I put only one '*' in the path: c:/*/*.txt  it doesn't work when I put [cd] or {c:,d:} before /*/*.txt or /**/*.txt   (I'm using windows can that be the problem?)

Comment: @Remonn - to be honest, I didn't try the suggestion ZyX proposed, I can only vouch for my original edit. You could be right that this is a windows problem.

Comment: @ZyX - In case you are reading this, could you shine your light on this. Your knowledge of Vim would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Lieven I only know that `vimgrep /<search>/ c:/**/*.txt d:/**/*.txt` must work and other my solutions *can* (that is why I said “try”, not “you can also use”). I can’t say anything more: at this time wine environment I use to test win32 vim was purged out (and it was purged more then a week ago).

Answer (score 7):

You can use grep as usually

```
:grep -R 'search-item' path1 path2
```

For more information see:

```
:h grep
```

Comment: this way works much better for me than vimgrep. vimgrep locks up my vim session and seems very slow.